# powershell Select-String cannot extract new-lines generated on the text stream from the pipe?

Tags: pipe, newline, whitespace, findstr, select-string

I want to find words contain keyword from text files. Example text file(test.txt) contains below strings.

`Here is unmatched part. 
" Happynimall happy-monkey:2 happy-cat:5 "
Here is unmatched part too. Here is unmatched part too.`

So I tried powershell commands as follow.

`` $(gc test.txt).replace(' ',"`n")|select-string 'monkey','cat' ``

But the result failed to extract only matching word line like this.

`"
Happynimall
happy-monkey:2
happy-cat:5
"`

By the way, cmd "findstr" works well in extracting matching word line generated in the pipe stream.
`` powershell -command "$(gc test.txt).replace(' ',"""`n""")"|findstr "monkey cat" ``

`happy-monkey:2
happy-cat:5`

Why cannot "select-string" extract matching word lines only? Why can "findstr" do that?
How can I make select-string give same result with findstr?
Is there anyone to help me understand about it and make select-string do that?
Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: ``replace(' ',"`n")`` -> `split(' ')`

Comment: @PetSerAl  Thanks for your help. It works well, great. Well, would you plsease inform about the reason that replace() could not do that?

Comment: If you replace space with new line in the string, then you will still have single string, which would be matched or not matched as whole. If you want to match them separately, then you should split, not replace.

Comment: @PetSerAl Well, thank you very much for detailed explanation. It is interesting what I've found is that command-sets with replace() are fairly quicker than those with split(). Thank you